# returning result of a function multiple times within the same function

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, pearson-correlation

I am trying to return a list of numbers that add up to 100 .. 11 times.

There are 3 numbers which are generated from a numpy random uniform distribution.

I want to add an if statement to see if the 1st, 2nd and 3rd numbers of each list (11 in total).. if plotted would have a Pearson correlation coefficient of >0.99.

At the moment, I am only able to generate 1 list of numbers which have a sum equal to 100.

I have following code:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

c1_high = 98
c1_low = 75
c2_high = 15
c2_low = 6
c3_high = 8
c3_low = 2

def mix_gen():
    while True:
        c1 = np.random.uniform(c1_low, c1_high)
        c2 = np.random.uniform(c2_low, c2_high)
        c3 = np.random.uniform(c3_low, c3_high)
        tot = c1+c2+c3

        if 99.99<= tot <=100.01:
            comp_list = [c1,c2,c3]
            return comp_list

my_list = mix_gen()
print(my_list)
```

so if i was to plot each component.. for example c1... i would get an R^2 value of >0.99.

[image]

I'm stuck at generating multiple lists inside the same function. I know this can be done outside the function.. using [mix_gen() for _ in range(11)].. but this will not work because I require this additional check of the peasron corr coeff before returning the 11 lists.

OBJECTIVE:

to return a dataframe with the following values:

```
   C1    C2    C3    sum
1   70    20    10    100
2   ..
3   ..
4   ..
5   ..
6   ..
7   ..
8   ..
9   ..
10  ..
11  90
R^2  1     1     1
```

Comment: use a counter flag inside the `if` and do not return from the `while` before you append eleven  lists into a container

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `yield`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be an option using a list of lists for the return

```
def mix_gen(number):
    flag = 0
    container = []
    while flag < number:
        c1 = np.random.uniform(c1_low, c1_high)
        c2 = np.random.uniform(c2_low, c2_high)
        c3 = np.random.uniform(c3_low, c3_high)
        tot = c1+c2+c3

        if 99.99 <= tot <= 100.01:
            flag += 1
            container.append([c1,c2,c3])

    return container
```

You call it with

```
my_list_of_lists = mix_gen(11)
```

Comment: Yes, it is indeed! I now need to somehow check the 11 items in the container for each component C1,C2 and C3 have an R^2 >0.99 =/.

Comment: I can do this with 'container_C1 = [item[0] for item in container]' .. but not sure how to revert back to the loop if the R^2 value >0.99  is not achieved. hmm

Comment: @Joey you should clearly state what your objective is. I am not sure why you want now to access a C1 value which does not comply with your initial requirements and, in consequence, you did not saved it in any container in the first place.

Comment: I have updated my original post to better describe my objective.

Comment: That's a really interesting problem to solve... however maybe getting the solution just trying random numbers is going to take too much computer effort. You should take into account the mathematical relation of the three regression lines to search for collections of points complying with the two requirements

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your proposition. Where would I 'search for collections of points' if there is no data to search in?

Comment: You are looking for points [situated in | defining] three lines C1, C2 and C3. Once you randomly get a first group of 11 points with r>0.99 (C1), and two random points for C2 complying each `C1point+C2point =< 100` then the other 9 C2 points can have only some limited values. Once you fix C1 and C2 lines, C3 is defined inmediately (as for C2, with a window for the point values determined by the required r2 value).

Comment: Ah right. I think I know what you are suggesting. Generate the C1s... and then the C2s ensuring that they both have r^2 values greater than 0.99 and that the sum of the two is less then 100. Then generate the C3 values based on this (100-sum(c1+c2)) and check the r^2. Does this sound about right?

Comment: yes. Note that generating only 2 points for C2 then the others get determined because two points already define a line and the other 9 points have to be in that line (around that line).